# Pyplot fill area below line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to fill the area below a simple line chart using pyplot. I'm aware of "fill_between", but I'm unable to work it into my code, primarily because I'm having trouble defining x and y, as in

```
fill_between(x,y)
```

Just the line plot portion of my code is below. I also think my ax.set_xticklabels is really inefficient, so any tips on that appreciated as well.

```
N = 31
ind = np.arange(N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='white')

ax.line = plot(days_len) #this is a list of 31 numbers e.g. 31,876, one for each day of July

ax.set_ylabel('Rides', fontsize = 22)
ax.set_xlabel('Day', fontsize = 22)
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,50000,5000))
ax.set_xticklabels(('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', 
'08','09','10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20',
'21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'))

#for chart styling purposes
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_color('red')
ax.spines["bottom"].set_color('red')

#returns only ticks for bottom and left of x and y axes
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks()[1:]) #to remove "0" at origin of y-axis

axes(ax).yaxis.grid(True, color='red') #just y-axis gridlines
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `fill_between`, `x` is the set of x-values where you want the fill to be. `y1` and `y2` are the curves you want to fill between. By default, `y2` is the x-axis. Since you are plotting 31 values, just use `range(31)` for `x`.

```
ax.fill_between(range(31), days_len)
```

As for the ticklabels, I would use `range` to generate the numbers, then use a list comprehension to turn them into a string (adding the leading zeros with the `zfill` string method).

```
ticklabels = [str(date).zfill(2) for date in range(1, 32)]
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels)
```

Comment: Thanks, Amy. This is very helpful. Before I saw your response, I figured out the first part with: x = ind
x.tolist()
fill_between(x, days_len, alpha = .2)